# How to enable Ehcache 3.x JSR-107 MBean operations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, jmx

Why the following ehcache.xml doesn't allow to clear caches via JMX (the Operations tab is disabled in JVisualVM for MBean for cache management and enabled for cache statistic)? I use spring boot framework and specify ehcache.xml file location via spring.cache.jcache.config property and just use @Cachable spring framework annotation.

```
<config
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">


  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults enable-management="true" enable-statistics="true"/> 
  </service>

  <cache alias="stringCache"> 
    <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
    <value-type>java.lang.String</value-type>
    <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
  </cache>

</config>
```

Comment: cross posted : https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/1993

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing cache entries is not supported by the JSR-107 specification. Only clearing the statistics is possible. To workaround that, you will have to create your own MBean.